# Optimal control problem with spike source and "split" state

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, dirac-operator

For $p \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the following problem:
\begin{equation} \label{1}
\begin{cases}
\operatorname{div}(a \nabla u ) = p\delta_{x_0} \quad \text{in } \Omega \\
u=0 \quad \text{on } \partial \Omega ;
\end{cases}
 \end{equation}
under the assumption that $a \in L^\infty$ is constant in some neighbourhood of $x_0$, i.e. $a(\mathbf{x})= a_0 \text{Id}$ for $\mathbf{x} \in B=B_{r_0}(x_0)$, $a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, we can look for a solution in the form
$$ u(x) = \psi(x) + K(x-x_0), $$
where $K(\cdot)$ is the fundamental solution (up to the constants $a_0,p$) of the Laplace operator and $\psi \in H^1(\Omega)$ satisfies a classical, well-posed, Neumann problem with data depending on $K|_{\Omega \setminus B}$. Note that the solution $u$ is not quite regular globally since it reads the singularity of $K$ at $x_0$.

Nevertheless, we can set up a control problem "away" from $x_0$ with the number $p$ as control and the quadratic tracking cost functional 
$$ \min_{p} \left( \frac{1}{2}  \| u(p) - u_{d} \|_{0, \Omega \setminus B}^2 + \frac{1}{2} |p|^2 \right), $$ 
for some desired state $u_d \in L^2$, $u(p)$ being the solution of the above problem (in the above sense!) corresponding to the control $p$.

I see some problems arising while trying to formulate go-to results like necessary optimality conditions: it is not clear what should be a suitable adjoint problem, since a weak formulation is only available for $\psi=\psi_p$, but the state $u$ also depends on $K=K_p$, making $u(p)$ not a trivial translation of $\psi$. Moreover, the choice of the $L^2(\Omega \setminus B)$ norm in the optimization was made to somehow regularize $u$, on the other hand:

- Is the control problem still meaningful, as we are trying - in principle - to approximate a global *a priori* chosen desired state taking into account only the behavior away from a fixed point?
- Working with integrals in $\Omega \setminus B$ rather than $\Omega$ gives rise to unwanted boundary terms in integrations by parts.

Are there any references for optimal control problems of this kind?

**Note:** I know that it is possible to set up a global weak formulation for this type of Dirac-source problems (see reference) using sharp functional analysis results on weighted spaces, but this is not known to be possible for larger classes of operators, like those I have to deal with in my research. Therefore, this is a model example and the "split" solution is most likely the only option.

**Reference:** Allendes, Alejandro, et al. "An a posteriori error analysis for an optimal control problem with point sources." ESAIM: Mathematical Modelling and Numerical Analysis 52.5 (2018): 1617-1650.